# Trying to identify an old sci-fi novel: a group of space travellers visiting a planet previously long-inhabited but regressed?

Tags: story-identification, novel, novella

I know this is a very long shot, but for years I've been trying to ID a sci-fi novel, quite likely the first I ever read.

1. Published pre-1982. Fairly short paperback, like an old Tor novel. Novella? Single story, not part of anthology.
2. A group of space travellers (likely human) come to visit (crash on?) a planet.
3. Discover planet was previously inhabited. I believe they find an old road.
4. Road leads to a city.
5. I think the city was inhabited by an alien race or a regressed human race. I vaguely remember they are apelike (no, not Planet of the Apes!), possibly lizard-like.
6. Conflict of course.
7. I seem to remember there was another, old spaceship that was discovered.
8. I *think* the cover showed a rocket, the road and perhaps the city in background. But that could be a figment.

I know, super, super vague. I wish I could provide more, sorry. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This could be [*Star Rangers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Rangers_(novel)) (also known as *The Last Planet*) by Andre Norton, originally from 1953.  It's a short book.  It's been decades since I read it; I'm going by the Wikipedia synopsis here.

A scoutship of the Stellar Patrol crashes on a mostly-uninhabited planet.  The crew includes reptile- and bird-like people.  The survivors meet up with the survivors of another wrecked spaceship, who have inhabited an abandoned city.  There's definitely conflict, a rebellion and some psychic combat. There's mention in the synopsis of natives, so I guess some of the original inhabitants were still around.

Could this be the cover you remember?

[image: The Last Planet cover]

This is the cover of the version I have from the early 80s:

[image: Star Rangers cover]

And this may be the cover @R.Hamper remembers:

[image: Three rangers and hiding robot cover]

Comment: Also my immediate thought.

Comment: Holy cow! That's it!! You and @DavidW nailed it and so fast! I've been thinking about that book on and off for years and basically given up hope that I'd ever identify it. I just stumbled across this site last night and I figured, what the heck, give it a try.

Comment: Apparently I only have a short time to edit,  so this is a continuation. Thank you, thank you!! Not sure how the reward system works on this site,  but I've up voted you all. Neither cover is the one I remember, I seem to recall a simpler, day time landscape,  but who knows. :) Now that I know the title, I'll scour the Internet for it!

Comment: I found the cover!! Unfortunately,  I don't seem to have enough authority yet to link images, but it is the one with the three "Rangers" and a hidden robot. Perhaps one of you could link it?       So, the elements of my memory were there: the ship, the road and the city. How i missed the robot I don't know.  Like some cover art, there may have been some license with the image, because I'm not sure there was a robot in the book. I do remember that my young self had some dissonance with the cover and perhaps that was it.

Comment: So, on top of it all, while searching for the cover art, I stumbled across a sci-fi fantasy blog run by a person who had the same book in their junior high school library, at nearly the same time in the SAME province!!! Our entire province has less than a million people. Apparently they spent a long time tracking down this book too. Wild.

Comment: @R.Hamper You're very welcome :-).  I've added the cover I think you're talking about, although there are a couple of variations with the same artwork but different titling.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. :)

Answer (score 5):

I wonder if you're remembering Andre Norton's [*Star Rangers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2945) (also released as *The Last Planet*).  It was originally published in 1953, but had several reprintings in the 1960s and 1970s.

The mixed-species, but predominantly human crew of a Stellar Patrol ship are stranded on an uncharted planet when their old, insufficiently supplied spaceship crashes.  They find a road buried in the sand that leads to a city where survivors of another crash are under the control of a projective telepath.  Again, these are mostly human, but there are also some reptilian-type Zacathians.

The telepath is defeated, freeing those in thrall to him, so he takes off and tries to enslave a group of natives.  The natives are very human-like, but slightly different; I don't think they were described as devolved or apelike though.

They didn't discover another spaceship, but they did find the original hall of leave-taking, and they were able to guide in another ship load of refugees from the collapse of the empire.

Comment: It is!! Wow! and thanks to you and @LAK! Amazing. See comments above. I can't swear it is the very first sci-fi I ever read,  but likely that it is and it is definitely the earliest I remember.  Makes sense that it was an Andre Norton book too, as I was getting into fantasy and D&D at the time. So stoked! I'm going to track that book down and get a copy! Again,  many thanks for extracting that memory worm!

Comment: PS Since that was so successful, I'm going to ask about an old fantasy novel next. Keep an eye out!  :)